# Mask both IPv4 and IPv6 in PHP

Tags: php, regex, ip

I'm trying to be able to mask the last part of both IPv4 and IPv6 strings in PHP, but at the same time. What I mean is, that 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.0.255 would both show 192.168.0.XXX and 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334 would turn into 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:XXX

Is this possible in PHP? I know with IPv4 I can just do this:

```
preg_replace('/([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)\\.[0-9]+/', '\\1.xxx', $text);
```

With this I can mask specifically IPv4, but because I'm not too familiar with Regex, I'm having trouble figuring this out.

Comment: Make another pattern for IPv6. Then combine the two patterns with `|` to match either of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a different method, that didn't involve Regex, and, in my opinion, made it a lot simpler for me to handle it. Plus, it allows for abbreviated IPv6 addresses.

```
if(strpos($ip, ':')){
      //IPv6
      $replace_num = strrpos($ip, ':') - strlen($ip) + 1;
      $ip = substr_replace($ip, 'xxxx', $replace_num);
}
else{
     //IPv4
     $replace_num = strrpos($ip, '.') - strlen($ip) + 1;
     $ip = substr_replace($ip, 'xxx', $replace_num);
}
```

This allows me to just use the fact of having ":" for IPv6 and "." for IPv4 to determine the type of IP address, and then just replace the last part of the string. Adding 1 to $replace_num is required as if not it will remove the last ":" or "." which isn't what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `|` to create a pattern with alternatives.

```
preg_replace('/((?:\d{1,3}\\.){3}|(?:[\da-f]{1,4}:){7})(?:[\da-f]{1,4}|\d{1,3})/', '$1xxx', $text);
```

Note that this won't work with abbreviated IPv6 addresses, since it specifically checks for 8 blocks of hex digits. Dealing with that is left as an exercise for the reader.